# Accessing properties from Java Binding Library Interface in Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, java-native-interface

I am getting an AbstractMethodError when trying to get X from a Java.Lang.Object.

```
class DataMessageHandler : Java.Lang.Object, IRouteManagerMessageHandler
{
      public void Process(Message p0)
      {
           var message = p0;
           var cartesian = Class.FromType(typeof(CartesianFloat));

           var value = (ICartesian)message.GetData(cartesian);
           var x = value.X();
      }
}
```

Where CartesianFloat is an implementation of ICartesian.

ICartesian:

```
[global::Java.Interop.JavaTypeParameters (new string [] {"T extends java.lang.Number"})]
public partial interface ICartesian : IJavaObject {

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.mbientlab.metawear.data']/interface[@name='Cartesian']/method[@name='x' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register ("x", "()Ljava/lang/Number;", "GetXHandler:Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesianInvoker, MetaWearAndroid")]
    global::Java.Lang.Object X ();

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.mbientlab.metawear.data']/interface[@name='Cartesian']/method[@name='y' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register ("y", "()Ljava/lang/Number;", "GetYHandler:Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesianInvoker, MetaWearAndroid")]
    global::Java.Lang.Object Y ();

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.mbientlab.metawear.data']/interface[@name='Cartesian']/method[@name='z' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register ("z", "()Ljava/lang/Number;", "GetZHandler:Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesianInvoker, MetaWearAndroid")]
    global::Java.Lang.Object Z ();

}
```

CartesianFloat:

```
        public unsafe CartesianFloat ()
        : base (IntPtr.Zero, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer)
    {
        if (Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        try {
            if (GetType () != typeof (CartesianFloat)) {
                SetHandle (
                        global::Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.StartCreateInstance (GetType (), "()V"),
                        JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                global::Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (Handle, "()V");
                return;
            }

            if (id_ctor == IntPtr.Zero)
                id_ctor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (class_ref, "<init>", "()V");
            SetHandle (
                    global::Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.StartCreateInstance (class_ref, id_ctor),
                    JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
            JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (Handle, class_ref, id_ctor);
        } finally {
        }
    }

    // This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesian
    global::Java.Lang.Object global::Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesian.X ()
    {
        return global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<Java.Lang.Object>(((ICartesian) this).X ());
    }

    // This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesian
    global::Java.Lang.Object global::Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesian.Y ()
    {
        return global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<Java.Lang.Object>(((ICartesian) this).Y ());
    }

    // This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesian
    global::Java.Lang.Object global::Com.Mbientlab.Metawear.Data.ICartesian.Z ()
    {
        return global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<Java.Lang.Object>(((ICartesian) this).Z ());
    }

}
```

If I try to  cast value as CartesianFloat, it says no method X() exists on value.

Putting a Watch on value, has a value of {(-0.062, 0.070, 1.010)}

Comment: what is `message.GetData(cartesian)` ??

Comment: @Sven-Michael Stübe , It is a CartesianFloat object

Comment: I mean what is it doing? What is messages? It's not declared in your code.

Comment: I mean what is it doing? What is messages? It's not declared in your code.

Comment: @Sven-Michael Stübe. Apologies, edited question. https://mbientlab.com/docs/metawear/android/latest/com/mbientlab/metawear/Message.html

Comment: do you have a mini sample somewhere on github? There are just too many followup questions I'd ask :D

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am porting a tutorial into Xamarin. The tutorial just outputs the CartesianFloat to display as a string in the logcat. I am trying to extract these values to display on the screen as a proof of concept. Here is the tutorial, at the part of code I am working on : https://youtu.be/E2ppFUGLaNM?list=PLiiW3P34smqakg9NVpfbGsS2vChYmqaDH&t=120. Here is the java code: https://github.com/mbientlab-projects/FreeFallDetector/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mbientlab/freefalldetector/MainActivity.java#L144

Comment: And just your binding project?

Comment: I built from the .aar generated from: https://github.com/mbientlab/Metawear-AndroidAPI

Answer (score 0):

Metwear API sends encoded data in BLE packet and you can decode it using following code. I translated it (than optimized) from their java code.

```
public void Process(Message p0)
  {
    var message = p0 as Bmi160ThreeAxisMessage;
    var data = message.GetData();
    var x = ((short)(data[1] << 8 | data[0])) / message.Scale;
    var y = ((short)(data[3] << 8 | data[2])) / message.Scale;
    var z = ((short)(data[5] << 8 | data[4])) / message.Scale;
}
```